# Is there a C# datetime library that can handle dates from present to 12,000 bc?

Tags: c#, datetime

That's pretty much it. I don't need high precision in the Paleolithic Era, but I would like to be able to represent these date without jumping through too many hoops.

Comment: @Jason: does it have to be written in C#? Do you need the source?

Comment: @John: No, it doesn't. But I would prefer it run under windows without installing, for example, the java run-time.

Comment: so, VB.NET would be ok, right?

Comment: Yes. VB.NET would be fine. :)

Comment: Gregorian Calendar or Julian? Jain or Chinese? Hebrew or Hindu (in which case, which one again)?

Comment: I just want to point out, that time precision drops before 1870 and by the time it moves below 0 AD it's practically useless, because time in Julian/Gregorian calendar runs differently so a number of days in 1000 years in Julian != number of days in 1000 years in Julian.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Noda Time](http://nodatime.org) supports times +/- 290 million years.

Comment: Thanks, Sam. That's what I Love about S.O. :)